# Laravel : How to pass one variable of one model for different queries to view and how to access it in view

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am learning laravel. I am confused at one point.

I have one model `Trader` which has one to one relationship with two other models `AgriculturalProduceMarketCommettee` and `CategoryMaster`. 
`traders` table has `apmc_id` and `category_id` as foreign keys. Now I want to show `traders_name`, `apmc_branch_name`, `category_name` in one table.

**Trader Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Trader extends Model
{
       /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'traders';

    // primary key
   public $primaryKey = 'traders_id';

    //timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

      /**
       * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
       *
       * @var array
       */
      protected $fillable = [
          'apmc_id','category_id', 'traders_name', 'traders_address','traders_contact_number'
      ];


    /**
 * Get the apmc that has the trader.
 */
public function apmc()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\AgriculturalProduceMarketCommettee', 'apmc_id');
}


    /**
 * Get the category that has the trader.
 */
public function categoryMaster()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CategoryMaster', 'category_id');
}

}
```

**TraderController**

```
public function index()
    {
        $traders = Trader::all();
        $traderApmc = Trader::with('apmc')->get();
        $traderCategory = Trader::with('categoryMaster')->get();
        return view('traders.tradersDetails', compact('traders','traderApmc','traderCategory'));
    }
```

**tradersDetails.blade.php : view**

```
 <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Trader Name</th>
                          <th>APMC Branch Name</th>
                          <th>Category Name</th>

                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          @if(count($traders) >= 1)
                          @foreach ($traders as $trader)

                        <tr>
                            <td> {{$trader->traders_name}} </td>
                            <td> {{$traderApmc->apmc->apmc_branch_name}} </td>  
                            <td> {{$traderCategory->categoryMaster->category_name}} </td> 
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach 
                        @else
                        <p>No records found!</p>
                        @endif
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
```

Now in `TraderController`, I am passing 3 different variables `'traders','traderApmc','traderCategory'` for one model `Trader` to view `tradersDetails` for 3 different queries. But in view the way I have used that variables will give me error of collection instance like

`Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Property [apmc] does not exist on this collection instance.`

How should I pass that variables and access that in view ? 
Please Guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: is apmc a column present in your traders table, or is it apmc_id?

Comment: `traders` table has `apmc_id` and `category_id` as foreign keys. I have mentioned that in question.

Comment: if that's the case, how are you trying to fetch "apmc" from the Traders model? the model reflects table being used. if it's a foreign key, what you do is fetch it from that table, so something like Category::where('id', $traders['category_id']->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using 3 variables you can combine then using:

```
$trader = Trader::with(['apmc','categoryMaster'])->get();
```

passing to your view:

```
return view('traders.tradersDetails', compact('traders'));
```

and you can use it your view:

```
@foreach ($traders as $trader)
   <tr>
       <td> {{$trader->traders_name}} </td>
       <td> {{$trader->apmc->apmc_branch_name}} </td>  
       <td> {{$trader->categoryMaster->category_name}} </td> 
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: the issue posted is, correct me if im wrong, this; Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Property [apmc] does not exist on this collection 
which basically states that the value apmc is not in the traders colelction.

Comment: @Poldo Worked!! thanks a lot for the help. I had searched for the solution how should I combined that queries in one so that I can use one variable in view. But was unable to find solution. Thanks to you. Learned new way.